# crashes my app [NSMutableArray1 removeAllObjects] iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

i use this code to check if any objects exist in my NSMutableArray
if yes i remove them all but it crashes although there are objects why?

```
    if([NSMutableArray1 count]==1)
    {
        [poemoptionslist removeAllObjects];
    }



    if ([NSMutableArray1 count]==0)
    {
        [poemoptionslist addObject: final1];
    }
```

CONSOLE OUTPUT

> 2010-10-18 03:42:13.166
>   app1[33398:207] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: '-[__NSCFArray
>   removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method
>   sent to immutable object'
>   *** Call stack at first throw: (  0   CoreFoundation
>   0x02e55b99 **exceptionPreprocess + 185
>     1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x02fa540e objc_exception_throw + 47
>     2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x02e0e238 +[NSException
>   raise:format:arguments:] + 136    3
>
>   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x02e0e1aa +[NSException
>   raise:format:] + 58   4
>
>   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x02e4d3c1 -[__NSCFArray
>   removeObjectAtIndex:] + 193   5
>
>   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x02dfe973 -[NSMutableArray
>   removeAllObjects] + 83    6
>
>   poemsoflove
>
>   0x0004dc8d -[submitpoem submitpoem:] +
>   18560     7   UIKit
>
>   0x003b77f8 -[UIApplication
>   sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119   8
>   UIKit
>
>   0x00442de0 -[UIControl
>   sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67     9
>
>   UIKit
>
>   0x00445262 -[UIControl(Internal)
>   _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527   10  UIKit
>
>   0x00443e0f -[UIControl
>   touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458    11 
>   UIKit
>
>   0x003db3d0 -[UIWindow
>   _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567  12  UIKit
>
>   0x003bccb4 -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
>   + 447     13  UIKit                               0x003c19bf _UIApplicationHandleEvent +
>   7672  14  GraphicsServices
>
>   0x033e6822 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
>     15  CoreFoundation
>
>   0x02e36ff4
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   + 52  16  CoreFoundation                      0x02d97807 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
>     17  CoreFoundation
>   0x02d94a93 __CFRunLoopRun + 979   18 
>   CoreFoundation
>   0x02d94350 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
>     19  CoreFoundation
>   0x02d94271 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97    20
>   GraphicsServices
>   0x033e500c GSEventRunModal + 217  21 
>   GraphicsServices
>   0x033e50d1 GSEventRun + 115   22  UIKit
>   0x003c5af2 UIApplicationMain + 1160
>     23  poemsoflove
>   0x00002728 main + 102     24  poemsoflove
>   0x000026b9 start + 53     25  ???
>   0x00000001 0x0 + 1 ) terminate called
>   after throwing an instance of
>   'NSException' Program received signal:
>   “SIGABRT”.

Guys there is no NSArray!

I save to NSUSerdefaults like this:

if ([mutable1 count]==0)
        {
            [mutable1 addObject: final1];
        }

```
    NSUserDefaults *list =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [list setObject:mutable1 forKey:@"favorites"];
    [list synchronize];
```

and i load data like this

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs1 =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if ( [prefs1 objectForKey:@"favorites"] != nil)
{
    mutable1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    mutable1 = [prefs1 objectForKey:@"favorites"];
```

and i get the objects! then when it runs the removeallobjects it crashes!

Comment: Can you post more information about the crash?  Messages, stack trace, etc?

Comment: You might want `[NSMutableArray1 count]>=1` because ==1 just checks if there is 1 and only 1.

Comment: can you show how you declared 'poemoptionslist' ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
mutable1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
mutable1 = [prefs1 objectForKey:@"favorites"];
```

Even though you've declared mutable1 to be an NSMutableArray, you are reassigning it to the object returned by your NSUserDefaults object.  This object is apparently an NSArray rather than an NSMutableArray, hence the crash.

You can load your NSMutableArray with the preferences array by doing something like this:

```
mutable1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[mutable1 addObjectsFromArray:[prefs1 objectForKey:@"favorites"]];
```

Comment: thank you so much i was seraching for hours about this problem!

Comment: Is there any other way other than allocating a whole new 'mutable1'. Like in `mutable1 = [prefs1 objectForKey:@"favorites"];` We dont need a alloc here.. I have tried `mutable1 = (NSMutableArray*)[prefs1 objectForKey:@"favorites"];` but failed :(

Comment: Sure, if the preference item @"favorites" is actually an array and you don't need to modify it, use `NSArray *faves = [prefs1 arrayForKey:@"favorites"];`.

Answer (score 1):

The error messages indicate that you're sending the message to an immutable array, which raises an exception. Uncaught exceptions lead to program termination.

How are you creating the array? The most common error that can lead to this is doing something like:

```
[mutableArray copy]
```

Even if the thing you're copying is mutable, the copy will be immutable. In that randomly chosen example, use mutableCopy insted.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you have set NSMutableArray1 to an instance of NSArray, not NSMutableArray or you declared NSMutableArray1 as a property of type NSArray vs. NSMutableArray.

Also, you should follow Cocoa / Objective-C naming conventions. Namely, class names start with upper case; variables take the form myArray1 (or something more descriptive, preferably).