# NSMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex, but then I need to move down

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

All,

I have strings stored in a NSMutableArray. When a certain condition is met elsewhere in the code, the object that is FIRST in the NSMutableArray (read, objectAtIndex:0) gets removed. After it is removed, I need to shift everything down an index. Here is my example:

```
/*
    Index/Value
    0 - one
    1 - two
    2 - three
    3 - four
    4 - five
    5 - six
    6 - seven
*/
//removes object...
[mArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
//I am missing something here...


//I want the value of the array to be as follows:
/*
    Index/Value
    0 - two
    1 - three
    2 - four
    3 - five
    4 - six
    5 - seven
*/
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT: The NSMutableArray is stored in NSUserDefaults. Is that what may be causing this not to work?**

**EDIT2: Because it is stored in NSUserDefaults, it changes to immutable. Check out the accepted answer for the correct way to do it. Details here: [crashes my app [NSMutableArray1 removeAllObjects] iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955969/crashes-my-app-nsmutablearray1-removeallobjects-iphone-sdk)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly you are storing an `NSMutableArray` to `NSUserDefaults` and then when you load it out of `NSUserDefaults` it throws an error when you try to mutate?

This is because when you retrieve the array from `NSUserDefaults` it will be an instance `NSArray` not `NSMutableArray` therefore you need to make a an instance of `NSMutableArray` to work with.

```
NSMutableArray *mArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:myArrayFromNSUserDefaults];
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I also found an answer here as well for those who may stop by later: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955969/crashes-my-app-nsmutablearray1-removeallobjects-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 7):

You're not missing anything. The indexes will be exactly like that after removing the object at index 0.

Comment: I thought this was the case, but it throws an error "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'"

Maybe I have something wrong somewhere else in my code.

Comment: That is because you do not have a mutable array. mArray needs to be an NSMutableArray either by creating a new one or calling mutableCopy (which will return a retained copy) on an existing array.

Comment: @James That error means that your array is actually a normal NSArray, not an NSMutableArray. Check the place you initialize your array to make sure it's really being created as an NSMutableArray.

Comment: @Nate: That's exactly what I thought, but it's definitely an NSMutableArray. Checked it and double checked it. It's weird.

Comment: How's your array initialized?

Comment: The NSMutableArray is stored in NSUserDefaults. Is that what may be causing this not to work?

Comment: omz: [prefs setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", nil] forKey:@"emptyPockets"] where *prefs is my NSUserDefaults.

Comment: NSUserDefaults always returns an immutable array. Although you are setting it to mutable it will return immutable so when get the value back also call mutableCopy.

Comment: The moral of this story is always post all relevant code, especially variable initialization. If Joe is correct, his comment should be added as an answer.

Comment: Joe is correct. I found the answer on how to do it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955969/crashes-my-app-nsmutablearray1-removeallobjects-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 0):

That should work. Are you doing something like this?

```
    NSMutableArray *mArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [mArray addObject:@"one"];
    [mArray addObject:@"two"];
    [mArray addObject:@"three"];

    [mArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"mArray at 0: %@",[mArray objectAtIndex:0]);
```